# How can I use gulp to concatenate bower_components that contain assets?

Tags: gulp, bower, bundling-and-minification

I'm developing a sample application which uses [bower](http://bower.io/) for it's dependency management and [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for it's build system.

I've used the [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) plugin to copy all of the relevant files from the `bower_components` directory into a `build/dist/bower_components` directory.

This all works perfectly, and I can open my application's `index.html` which properly points to each of these files and they properly point to the assets.

My next step is to concatenate the `bower_components` so that I have a single CSS and a single JS file along with all of the assets (fonts, images, etc.). I have used [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) to bundle all of the components, and it seems to work nicely.

However, some of the CSS and JS files being combined use relative paths to reference assets which are now incorrect since everything is in a single file:

- FontAwesome
- Bootstrap
- and a custom bower component we are creating

**Is there a standard solution for fixing the assets?**

Do I need to use gulp to update the asset references or perhaps use a different plugin?

Comment: @DavinTryon - According to the gulp blacklist (https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json), it has been blacklisted in favor of gulp-useref so I was attempting to use the "best practice" here. Do you think I should switch anyway and use the blacklisted one? Thanks!

Comment: gulp-useref looks like the better option then.

Comment: I can't answer the specific question, as I'm using SASS versions/stylesheets of the components you mentioned (Bootstrap, Font Awesome), where you typically override a variable to define where your assets are located and use the ```@import``` directive from a single ```main.scss``` file to get everything into one file. So if switching to SASS is an option, I can do a short write-up on how the problem is solved in that case.

Comment: @KalleBjörklid I know how to do it with SASS as what you describe is fairly easy; I was hoping for a more "minimalist" approach though using just the compiled CSS/JS so that it could have fewer dependencies.

Comment: we can just update the file to point to the copy inside of our bower_components using gulp-replace plugin.

Comment: @Kanti - That's actually what I wound up doing. If you care to elaborate and add an answer, I would be happy to award you the bounty :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [gulp-replace plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) we can concatenate bower_components assests.

For example:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('fix-paths', ['minify'], function() {
    gulp.src('public/css/site.css')
        .pipe(replace('../', '../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

Comment: This is the exact type of answer I was looking for and eventually the solution that I came to as well. In order to fix the paths, I had to manually update the CSS and replace the paths with the `gulp-replace` plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the gulp inject plugin to inject the concatenated file to the html. Something like this -

```
gulp.task('html', ['styles', 'vendor-js', 'templateCache', 'scripts'], function() {
    gulp.src('./*.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['./dist/js/**/*.js'])
            .pipe(angularFilesort()), {
                'ignorePath': 'dist/js',
                'addRootSlash': false,
                'addPrefix': 'scripts'
            }))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['./dist/vendors/**/*.js', '!./dist/vendors/less/less.js'], {
            read: false
        }), {
            'name': 'vendors',
            'ignorePath': 'dist/vendors',
            'addRootSlash': false,
            'addPrefix': 'vendors'
        }))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['./dist/css/*.css'], {
            read: false
        }), {
            'ignorePath': 'dist/css',
            'addRootSlash': false,
            'addPrefix': 'styles'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Let me know if you need any more code.

Comment: Be careful to notice the options I am passing to give it a desired path.

Comment: This is the general approach that should be taken, but my case was a bit more specific in that I needed to update the asset paths for some of the bower_components, so I had to use the `glup-replace` plugin as suggested by the accepted answer. Thanks for the additional answer though!

Answer (score 1):

For **CSS**, I would suggest using [gulp-rework](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rework), which wraps [rework](https://github.com/reworkcss/rework) that has a number of very helpful plugins.

One of these is [url](https://github.com/reworkcss/rework-plugin-url/), which provides a function for updating the urls contained within CSS.

An example where this is useful, is in CSS that contains no path to replace; e.g.

> url(backgroundimage2.png)

Or, you want to perform different alterations of the URL based on type (e.g. only images, not web fonts).

A function can be composed that tests for asset type; the following example processes only image files:

```
   // CSS
  .pipe(cssFilter)
  .pipe(rework(reworkUrl(function (url) {
      // modifications on url, e.g. using http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/   
      if (url.match(/[^/]+(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/))
      {
          return '/lib/img/' + url.replace('../', '');
      }
      else
      {
          return url;
      }

   })))
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found same problem so gone through various solutions and one of them was to replace the content of css in this answer itself. After looking the font-awesome.css it was clear that it refers relative path to reach fonts folder. same was the case with bootstrap css. Solution is simple now always make sure to keep css and fonts folder at same level and copy data. Even include your app specific min files here. Single place for all dist files makes life easy